# how to take /use serial input in verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga

I want to control a servo motor using an 8-bit input to generate a PWM. Here's my problem: I need to take the serial input through a MAX 232 from PC and I don't know how to do it. A sample code would be helpful too...
TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a UART (a Universal Asynchronous Receiver/Transmitter) to your FPGA design. Connect the TX and RX signals from the UART to the MAX232, convert them to RS-232 voltage levels, and then connect to the PC. You should be able to find sample code on your own, now that you know what to search for.